# PDO doesn't care about uppercase/lowercase letters

Tags: php, sql, pdo

So i've got a MYSQL query which looks like

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=:login and password=:password
```

I am using **PDO** and no matter in which way I will write a password it will select it, like if I've got "passWord" in database and my :password will be "password" it will still get it, any solution how to fix it?

Comment: You shouldn't store your password in plaintext in your database. Usw `password_hash` and `password_verify`.

Comment: probably your db have text field case insensitive.

Comment: but what if I need to actually show passwords sometimes? I am doing something that later will need to show passwords

Comment: For what purpose do you need to later show the password? I would never enter any sensitive information like passwords anywhere if I know they don't care about storing it safely. Seriously, hash your passwords.

Comment: All the recent news of major corporations foolishly storing plaintext passwords getting breached and having those passwords dumped should be a major indicator to you that this practice is unacceptable. And you should certainly not ever need to display those passwords to anyone, even the user who is supposed to remember them.

Answer (score -1):

This issue is that your field in the database is not case sensitive.  You can fix that with this statement...

```
ALTER TABLE users CHANGE password password VARCHAR(50) BINARY NOT NULL;
```

On as side note, if you are dealing with passwords I suggest you hash them, [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) is the link.

Comment: Don't suggest old methods like md5 or sha1, they are already broken. Use `password_hash()` with `password_verify()`. The link you gave even tells you about that :p

Comment: Hehehe, Did you read this paragraph in [the document you linked to](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) called ? **Why are common hashing functions such as md5() and sha1() unsuitable for passwords?** Obviously not!